# How to use Stage and Stage.stageVideos to play the currenty playing video

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have developed a mobile AIR app in which a swf is placed over the video and when it (swf) clicked pause the main video and start a new video linked to swf over the main video and play/pause button appear on the swf linked video and when the play/pause button clicked it play/pause the main video which is in the background.

Can I use the `stage` and its property `stage.stageVideos` to play pause the video which is currently playing. My `onPlayButton`is only have `mediaPlayer.play();`.

I have a `fullScreen` button which have following code:

```
private function onFSClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(stage.displayState) 
    {
        case "normal":
            stage.displayState = "fullScreen";
            break;
        case "fullScreen":
        default:
            stage.displayState = "normal";
            break;
    }
}
```

The `fullScreen` button works with main video and when swf linked video play over main video then it also works for that swf linked video .

Can I able do same with the play/pause button using Stage as happen in the `fullScreen` button. I am new to AS3 and I start learning about the stage but find confusing. How could replace `mediaPlayer.play();` and `mediaPlayer.pause();` to Stage so that any video currently playing can be play/pause by button.

Comment: You just wrote almost four lines in one sentence. You should format your question better, as I don't understand what's exactly your problem. For sure, you cannot just use `StageVideo` - it's a hardware accelerated one and I guess for now you're using simple Video?

Comment: Yes, I am using simple video but I want to use stage because as in the question I have two videos which play over each other   and play/pause button works only for main video but I want to use play/pause button for the video which is currently playing as `fullScreen` button works in the above codes.